# UiKit 3 событие компонента Tab не срабатывает

Tags: javascript, события, uikit

Нужно было, чтобы при показе активной вкладки вызывалась функция calcTax().

```
<ul class="uk-tab-left uk-form-controls" id="tarif-tab">
    <li class="tarif">
        <a href="#1">
            <span>Тариф 1</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="tarif">
        <a href="#2">
            <span>Тариф 2</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="tarif">
        <a href="#3">
            <span>Тариф 3</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Попытался сделать так.

```
UIkit.tab('#tarif-tab', {connect: '#tarif-descr', animation: 'uk-animation-fade'});

UIkit.util.on(document, 'show', '#tarif-tab', calcTax());

function calcTax(){
   console.log(123)    
}
```

Но событие не срабатывает.

Comment: No, this question about Uikit events.

Comment: Нет, эта ошибка у вас из-за того, что вы не передаете функцию. Вы передаете результат выполнения функции `calcTax`. Прочитайте внимательно ответы по ссылке. Ну или просто сделайте так `UIkit.util.on(document, 'show', '#tarif-tab', calcTax);`

Comment: Событие срабатывает 1 раз и в вашем варианте не работает вообще. https://codepen.io/blazer69064/pen/xxbRBey ошибка в консоли.

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал вам 3 вещи. 1. **НЕ** используйте библиотеки, у которых в документации есть ошибки и примеры которых не работают. 2 Исправьте ваш вопрос, уберите оттуда **явную** ошибку (на которую ссылается ответ-дубликат). 3. Посмотрите ответ на enso, он решит вашу проблему https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47370132/uikit-3-event-is-not-working